# Non-exclusive style rules with CSS classes in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

Is it possible to have multiple options in the Style menu that set their own CSS class, but are not mutually exclusive?

For example, I want to have something similar to this:

```
stylesSet: [
    {name: 'Very Large Padding',
     element: 'p',
     attributes: {
         class: 'very-large-padding',
     }},
    {name: 'Alternative Font',
     element: 'p',
     attributes: {
         class: 'alternative-font',
     }},
]
```

In CSS then, something like:

```
.very-large-padding { padding: 4242px; }
.alternative-font { font-family: "MyFont", sans-serif; }
```

This works, but the problem is that I cannot have both "Very Large Padding" and "Alternative Font" activated at the same time. Is there a solution to this, that involves setting styles via CSS instead of inline `style` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block styles in CKEditor 4 cannot be combined. However, you can use inline elements (i.e. `span`):

```
{
    name: 'Very Large Padding',
    element: 'span',
    attributes: {
        class: 'very-large-padding',
    }
},
{
    name: 'Alternative Font',
    element: 'span',
    attributes: {
        class: 'alternative-font',
    }
},
```

which results in:

```
<p><span class="alternative-font">Fo<span class="very-large-padding">oB</span>ar</span></p>
```

or create a hybrid style:

```
{
    name: 'Very Large Padding with Alternative Font',
    element: 'span',
    attributes: {
        class: 'very-large-padding alternative-font',
    }
},
```

Comment: This indeed answers my question, though it doesn't solve my actual situation, because besides "very large padding" I also have "not so very large padding" and "completely huge padding" and "micro padding". With inline styles I can easily end up with having multiple paddings on a single element. Even if using style (i.e. inline CSS instead of CSS classes, same thing can happen, but this time every style will be on its own span element. This is a seriously missing feature, as far as I'm concerned. Blah blah...